# Very Dark Windows 7 Screen

Tags: windows-7, display

My Gateway laptop -Windows 7- screen became too dark a few days ago after I finished installing Windows automatic update. I can see nothing unless I use a flashlight. Windows login screen is the only bright screen for few seconds. What should I do to resolve this issue?

I checked power-saving/ Power Options settings and rebooting in Safe Mode. I tried to lower the refresh rate but it did not allow me. The laptop adapter type is ATI Radeon Xpress series. I calibrated display color. I uninstalled and reinstalled the adapter. I tried to update the driver but the driver is up to-date. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it work in Safe Mode?

Comment: I checked it in safe mode and it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try the calibrate color function in Windows 7. Under personalization/display? Is this under all users? Because your login-display is correct. You could try adding a user and see if it helps. (Just to troubleshoot if it's only in your user-profile)

Comment: I followed your suggestion and I still have dark screen. do you have another suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Did you change or recreate a new power-setting? Just checking them is often not enough. Try the answer [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/turning-off-windows-7-auto-dimming-on-desktop/4954ba46-27a3-4415-9f00-d76056694334).

Comment: I just created a new power-setting, still the same dark screen. Do you think its a hardware issue?

Comment: You said your login-screen is bright, so a hardware issue seems out of the question. It could still be a driver issue (or malware). But to exclude a hardware issue you could try a live-cd of Linux. (You did also try creating a new user and logging in as that user?) You could also delete the graphics adapter/driver **and not** install another. Just let Windows detect it or choose VGA-compatible.

Comment: Wait. You said the login-screen is there for "just a second". Does your screen become dark while still on the login-prompt. Then it could be a hardware issue (The backlight). You could try getting in the BIOS. If you let it sit there for a while see if it also turns dark within a minute. If it does, it is definitively the backlight. Further you could try the LiveCD of a Linux distro to check the backlight "under stress". (Maybe the BIOS screen is not stress enough to cause it to fail)

Comment: Thanks RIK. I entered into the BIOS and it was totally dark. And I remembered it flickered before it became totally dark (but it didn't flicker all the time). Is there a way to find out if its a backlight issue or the inverter board or just a cable issue. Also yesterday suddenly the screen was bright for about one hour and I turned the laptop off. When I tried to use it went dark again. Thanks

Comment: I'm not really a *hardware-man* so i wouldn't know. You could [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=Gateway+laptop+backlight+problem). I found [this](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/60750-35-backlight-inverter) but look around. You could first check the cables and if that does not resolve it you could consult a repairman. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you Rik for all answers. I will take it to the repair shop.